# How do I edit GridViewColumn.CellTemplate inside a ListView in Blend?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, listview, expression-blend

I usually use Blend to edit DataTemplates, it’s a very nice tool for this. But I haven’t figured out how to edit the GridViewColumn.CellTemplate deep inside a ListView with Blend. Is this possible?

Example of a ListView:

```
   <ListView>
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Width="200"
                                Header="Name">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBox Background="AliceBlue"
                                     Text="{Binding CarName}" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn Width="100"
                                Header="Color">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBox Background="Pink"
                                     Text="{Binding CarColor}" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>

    </ListView>
```

Comment: Ya it should be, you'll just do the same Edit Template->Edit additional->edit generated thing you do down through the nodes until you get to the template you're looking for.

Comment: I have tried all edit template things I could find :-/. Edit Template->Edit Current doesn't help. And Edit Additional Templates->ItemTemplate / ItemContainerStyle / ItemsPanel also doesn't give me anything I could use for this scenario :-(

Comment: nah once you get down to your template level there should be another one somewhere for like Edit generated content or something like that, I'd have to look and see what exactly it is.

Comment: any help on this?